# Make responders gem a dependency in gemspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a gem which requires the 'responders' gem. Below I've posted a section of my .gemspec file. Whenever I install my gem I always get the responders/rails-upgrade error message. Why would this be happening when an app is using my gem? Are these dependencies correct?

```
s.add_development_dependency 'bundler', '~> 1.8'
s.add_development_dependency 'rake', '~> 10.4'

s.add_dependency 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
s.add_dependency 'rails_12factor', '~> 0.0.3'
s.add_dependency 'responders', '~> 2.1'
```

Comment: What's "the responders/rails-upgrade error message"?

Comment: It is: 'The controller-level `respond_to' feature has been extracted to the `responders` gem. Add it to your Gemfile to continue using this feature: gem 'responders', '~> 2.0' Consult the Rails upgrade guide for details.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was being too strict with the gem dependency. It needed to be:

```
s.add_dependency 'responders', '~> 2.0'
```